# Ways of putting n indistinguishable objects into exactly k boxes out of n boxes

Tags: combinatorics

> For integers $k$ and $n$ satisfying $1 \le k \le n$, let $b(k, n)$ be the number
>    of ways of putting $n$ indistinguishable objects into $n$ distinguishable
>    boxes such that exactly $k$ boxes are non-empty.
>
> $(a)$ Give a formula for $b(k, n)$.
>
> $(b)$ Making direct use of your answer to part $(a)$, find a simple formula for the
>   sum $b(1, n) + b(2, n) + \ldots + b(n - 1, n) + b(n, n)$.

For part $a$, I have found the answer $b(k, n) = \binom nk \cdot \binom {n + k - 1}{k - 1}$.

But when I try to do part $$b, I cannot do anything.

Is there something wrong with my answer for part $a$? If not, can you please explain part $b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to part a) doesn't look right to me.  You seem to be thinking, "There are ${n\choose k}$ ways to choose which $k$ boxes we will use, and then there are ${n-k-1\choose k-1}$ ways to put $n$ items in those boxes, by stars and bars."  This comes close, but it overlooks the fact that stars and bars counts some cases where you leave some of the $k$ boxes empty.  After choosing the $k$ boxes, put one item in each box.  Now you can distribute the remaining $n-k$ items in the $k$ chosen boxes.

As to part b, consider that when you distribute the $n$ items into the boxes, there is always at least one non-empty box.

Comment: For part (b): using you logic we can evaluate the sum easily, but the question asks us to make direct use of the answer to part (a)...  To be clear, I think your way (combinatorial) is much much better, but the question seems to ask us to do algebraic manipulation of answers to (a), which IMHO is much harder (I'm haven't figured out how).

Comment: @antkam I interpret part b) to mean simply, "substitute your formula for $b(k,n)$ into this expression, and give a formula for the sum."

Comment: You mean substitute the expressions for $b(k,n)$ on the summation side (LHS), and then simply write down the answer on the RHS, based on the combinatorial reasoning?  Without algebraically manipulating the actual terms of the summation?  Maybe you're right, coz the alternative seems rather hairy (unless I'm missing some obvious telescoping effect or well known identities).

Comment: @antkam Yes, that's exactly how I interpreted it.